# NoClassDefFoundError on javax.swing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, swing, libgdx

I am using `KryoNet` and `Javax Swing` and i am having problems running my app on my android device. First i got a `NoClassDefFoundError` on `com.esotericsoftware.krynet.Client`. I found this strange since it is referenced in the core project and should, afaik, reachable for the android project like all other java jars.

So i added `kryonet` to the android `libs` folder as well and got rid of that error. But then the same error popped up for `Javax swing`. I believe these classes reside in java `rt.jar` so i did the same but this got me a `GC overhead limit exceeded` error.

I just cannot seem to get my client running, below is the logcat dump:

```
09-22 19:33:17.054: W/dalvikvm(18600): VFY: unable to resolve static method 13924: Ljavax/swing/JOptionPane;.showInputDialog (Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;ILjavax/swing/Icon;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
09-22 19:33:17.054: D/dalvikvm(18600): VFY: replacing opcode 0x77 at 0x0029
09-22 19:33:17.054: W/dalvikvm(18600): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame; (1425)
09-22 19:33:17.054: W/dalvikvm(18600): Link of class 'Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame;' failed
09-22 19:33:17.054: D/dalvikvm(18600): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x368b at 0x67 in Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient;.<init>
09-22 19:33:17.095: I/dalvikvm(18600): Could not find method java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater, referenced from method mg.realmofradiance.client.ChatClient$1.disconnected
09-22 19:33:17.095: W/dalvikvm(18600): VFY: unable to resolve static method 13056: Ljava/awt/EventQueue;.invokeLater (Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
09-22 19:33:17.095: D/dalvikvm(18600): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0005
09-22 19:33:17.095: W/dalvikvm(18600): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame; (1425)
09-22 19:33:17.095: W/dalvikvm(18600): Link of class 'Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame;' failed
09-22 19:33:17.105: W/dalvikvm(18600): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame; (1425)
09-22 19:33:17.105: W/dalvikvm(18600): Link of class 'Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame;' failed
09-22 19:33:17.105: I/dalvikvm(18600): Could not find method mg.realmofradiance.client.ChatClient$ChatFrame.setNames, referenced from method mg.realmofradiance.client.ChatClient$1.received
09-22 19:33:17.105: W/dalvikvm(18600): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13972: Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame;.setNames ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
09-22 19:33:17.105: D/dalvikvm(18600): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
09-22 19:33:17.105: W/dalvikvm(18600): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame; (1425)
09-22 19:33:17.105: W/dalvikvm(18600): Link of class 'Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame;' failed
09-22 19:33:17.105: W/dalvikvm(18600): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame; (1425)
09-22 19:33:17.105: W/dalvikvm(18600): Link of class 'Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame;' failed
09-22 19:33:17.105: I/dalvikvm(18600): Could not find method mg.realmofradiance.client.ChatClient$ChatFrame.addMessage, referenced from method mg.realmofradiance.client.ChatClient$1.received
09-22 19:33:17.105: W/dalvikvm(18600): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13964: Lmg/realmofradiance/client/ChatClient$ChatFrame;.addMessage (Ljava/lang/String;)V
09-22 19:33:17.105: D/dalvikvm(18600): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001e
09-22 19:33:17.105: W/dalvikvm(18600): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41855da0)
09-22 19:33:17.105: E/AndroidRuntime(18600): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1651
09-22 19:33:17.105: E/AndroidRuntime(18600): Process: mg.realmofradiance.client.android, PID: 18600
09-22 19:33:17.105: E/AndroidRuntime(18600): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.swing.JOptionPane
09-22 19:33:17.105: E/AndroidRuntime(18600):    at mg.realmofradiance.client.ChatClient.<init>(ChatClient.java:84)
09-22 19:33:17.105: E/AndroidRuntime(18600):    at mg.realmofradiance.client.RealmOfRadianceClient.create(RealmOfRadianceClient.java:19)
09-22 19:33:17.105: E/AndroidRuntime(18600):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:236)
09-22 19:33:17.105: E/AndroidRuntime(18600):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
09-22 19:33:17.105: E/AndroidRuntime(18600):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

It stops on the first line where Swing is needed. On my server app Swing works just fine, just not as much swing gui as in the client. Afaik swing should be compatible with android. Below is the line where my code breaks, line 84 on class ChatClient.

```
String input = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "IP:",
"Connect to lobby", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
null, null, "127.0.0.1");
```

On the server side, which is working, i am using a simple swing Jframe (which however is not being shown on my android device. So maybe android is not compatible with swing, still i am sure i read it should transform swing panes into a simplified UI on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not support the Swing graphics library as it has it's own. Use [AlertDialog](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog).

Comment: Do you have any idea why krynet client class had the same error?

Comment: Maybe you didn't have it checked in Project Properties->Java Build Config-> Order and Export.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I did have it checked in the core project. I had to copy and reference the jar again in the android project too. But afaik everything in the core project should automatically be referenced in the android project since the latter references the core already.

Comment: It should, but it isn't. I often have to manually check it in the Android project even though it's already checked in the core project. The compiler won't complain, but at runtime the classes will be missing. Copying the jar over may have caused it to get checked automatically because there was now a new jar in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Android phones don't have the `javax.swing` package. You will have to figure something else put for your app.